# Can the Vulcan nerve pinch kill someone?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Although Vulcans typically aren't into unnecessary killing, would they be able to kill someone with the Vulcan nerve pinch?

Answer (score 9):

According to the show's creator; Gene Roddenberry (writing in "[The Making of Star Trek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Making_of_Star_Trek)") the Vulcan Nerve Pinch works works thusly:

> *[The] Spock pinch [is] applied with the fingers of the right hand to the
>   area on top of the right shoulder near the base of the neck [and]
>   **blocks blood and nerve responses to the brain [which] produces instant
>   unconsciousness***

It stands to reason that if one was blocking blood flow to the brain (sufficient to cause unconsciousness), that continuing to do so would prove deadly over time.

Comment: Five Finger Death Pinch